# Permissions for folder picker Xamarin.Android without using All Files Access

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions, android-permissions

I have developed an Android app for field data capturing.  It allows the user to capture biological data and save to a location on the phone.  It is required that the user can select a location to save, and that requires a folder browser.  I recommend that the user only use the SD card for safety and practical reasons in the field.  No Network coverage is normally available, so the user needs to download the data from the SD card to their phone manually and for that, I don't want the the user to battle to find the data in some obscure android internal location, often hidden when trying to access via a Laptop or PC.

So I need the folder browser so the user can select a location on the SD card. I created my own folder browser and it works fine.  However, I am trying to publish my app on Google Play and they absolutely hate the idea that the user may manage their data on their own phone ;-).  Ok, not in so many words, but still, they don't want me to ask for All files access on Android, which seems the only way I can manage files (Create folders and read and write).

My Target API is 31.

Does anyone know how to get this kind of thing running and make Google happy at the same time?  Perhaps a different folder picker?

I tried many different permissions to not have to use All Files Access, but no luck.  If I only use  READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, I cannot create folders or write files to the SD card.

Comment: If you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE the user can pick any folder on your device inclusive those on the removable micro sd card. Not a single permission needed. After that you can create as many sub folders and files in that folder as you wisch.

Comment: `so the user needs to download the data from the SD card to their phone ` ? What do you have in mind? If the data is on the card and the card is in the phone then i would say that the data is in the phone: nothing to download.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you, I will have a look at that.  I did attempt it in the beginning, but got frustrated with trying to get an absolute file path from the URI.  As you know, the first part is encoded with.  Something like "tree/primary:and/then/the/decoded/path"

Comment: @blackapps No the user needs to be able to save their data on a folder of their choice on the SD card to be able to manually download it to their PC.  We work in remote areas with no network coverage, so its important that the data are saved to the SD card.  Also, if the device gets wet or busted, the user must be able to get the SD card into another device, select the working directory, and carry on.  The data are saved in a SQLite database and then when the user wants to "convert" it, its converted into a few separate csv files for their convenience.

Comment: You should not try to get an absolute path to begin with. Use that content scheme directly. Use SAF.

Comment: `As you know, the first part is encoded with. Something like "tree/primary:and/then/the/decoded/path` No. It starts with content://. Uri.toString().

Comment: `the user needs to be able to save their data on a folder of their choice on the SD card to be able to manually download it to their PC. ` No it can be any folder on external storage.

Comment: @blackapps I will try that, thank you.  Will let you know if I get a solution working based on this.  Thanks.

Comment: "No it can be any folder on external storage." Nope.  Must be removeable storage.  Phone "external storage" will not do.  Or perhaps I misunderstood that.  Also, the user needs to create or choose the folder on the SD card so they can find it again easily.  I do not want Android's obscure file storage to confuse the user.  The files need to be in the folder they created at first glance.

Comment: @blackapps I will let you know about the SAF.  Thanks a lot